# Android: Rendering real time values

Tags: android

Is there any open source engine available to render real time values in the shape of line chart and other types of chart. As the data passed using the web it will dynamically update itself and plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using [AChartEngine](http://www.achartengine.org/) to draw line charts.

It only provides plotting functionality.
Implementing real time data binding is your job.

**ADDED**

JFreeChart is the most famous one in Java, but it does not support Android since it uses Swing.

AFreeChart is a port of JFreeChart for android supprts.

http://code.google.com/p/afreechart/

Screenshots: http://afreechart.googlecode.com/svn/doc/screenshot/index.html

I am not sure it provides types of charts you want to use, but I think there are not many alternatives and this one may be the best.

Comment: AChartEngine is not supported for all types of charts?.:(

Comment: @iMaxBingo I have updated my answer, but I am not sure it will help you.

Comment: does AFreeChat supports for real time plotting

Comment: @iMaxBingo What you call `real time plotting` is, as I understand, updating plots if the data in data container is changed. So, you have to implement: fetching data from web and putting those new data to the data container and let the plot redraw using updated data container.

Comment: I already handle the backend procedure to get data over the web and put in a data model. now I want to assign that model to the graph as the data changed in the model the graph automatically updates itself.
The data changed rate is in milliseconds.

Comment: @iMaxBingo Then you should call some function like `redrawPlot` (there will be a function with different name. It's just as an example.) every new data comes in, or if you don't want the plot to blink too frequently, call `redrawPlot` in every 10 ~ 100 updates. This is the way how data binding works. Actually, I also have experience that updating plots every 0.5 seconds with real time data, and I used this approach.

Answer (score 1):

GraphView: http://www.jjoe64.com/p/graphview-library.html

It supports only line chart and barchart for now, but it has really small footprint and support dynamic data as well. Not very complex.

They have dynamic data example in their demos.

Comment: After getting some strange compatibility problem with Android 4.0.4 while updating the chart (dynamic graph)... I had to switch to AChartEngine..